# iOS RestKit disable sslv3 client-side

Tags: ios, poodle-attack, sslv3

I have disabled the sslv3 on the server side but I want to make sure if I can do something from the client side (iOS app).

I'm using this library in my project: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

I run some tests for the server like www.ssllabs.com web site and it shows that my server is secure sslv3 is disabled. I would like to do something even if someone tries to force SSL over TLS on the iOS side.